# C++ Cant set an object to a return object of a method

Tags: c++, object, interface

I need to create a class with represents a password, I also need an interface with has a method that creates a password object and another class ( Generator ) that implements the interface....

In main I need to create an object with the normal constructor and another object using the said generator.

```
class Password
{
    private:
        Password& operator=(const Password&);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Password&);
        friend bool operator==(const Password&, const Password&);
        string password;
    public:
        Password(string);
        string Encrypt() const;
};

Password::Password(string pass) :password(pass) {}

string Password::Encrypt() const
{
    string encryptedPass = password;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
        encryptedPass[i] = '*';
    return encryptedPass;
}

bool operator==(const Password& pass1, const Password& pass2)
{
    return pass1.password == pass2.password;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Password& pass)
{
    output << "Password: " << pass.password;
    return output;
}

Password& Password::operator=(const Password& pass)
{
    this->password = pass.password;
    return *this;
}
```

This is the interface and Generator

```
class IPassword
{
    public:
        virtual Password GenerateSaltedPass(string pass, int salt) = 0;
        virtual Password GenerateNewPass(string pass) = 0;
};

class PassGenerator:public IPassword
{
    public:
        virtual Password GenerateSaltedPass(string, int);
        virtual Password GenerateNewPass(string);
};

Password PassGenerator::GenerateSaltedPass(string pass, int salt)
{
    string aux = pass;
    for (int i = 0; i < salt; i++)
        aux += (rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * 90 + 65);
    return Password(aux);
}

Password PassGenerator::GenerateNewPass(string pass)
{
    return Password(pass);
}
```

I am comparing and printing said passwords as a way of checking if it works...
Here is the main function

```
int main(void)
{
    Password* pass1 = new Password("12345");
    IPassword* Generator = new PassGenerator();
    Password* pass2 = &Generator->GenerateNewPass("12345");
    Password* saltedPass = &Generator->GenerateSaltedPass("1234", 4);
    cout<<"Passwords are same?  " << (pass1 == pass2) << endl;
    cout << *pass1 << endl; 
    cout << *pass2 << endl;
    cout << *saltedPass << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the problem I have is that for pass1 it prints "12345"
but for pass2 and pass3 it prints nothing... And I have no idea why.

Sry for my bad english.

Comment: For reference: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: First and foremost [you don't need `new` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) or pointers for that matter. Also [please don't use `rand()` for anything that requires actual security](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) or randomness for that fact.

Comment: Hint: Don't take addresses of temporaries.

Comment: `rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * 90 + 65`: Avoid magic numbers: You probably need something like `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"[randomIndex]`.

Comment: your code would be easier to read (and most likely also more correct) if you used `&` and `*` more sparingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Password PassGenerator::GenerateNewPass(string pass)
```

`GenerateNewPass()` returns a `Password` object.

```
Password* pass2 = &Generator->GenerateNewPass("12345");
```

The address of the returned object is saved in `pass2`. However, returned values are always temporary objects, and they get destroyed immediately. This results in leaving a dangling pointer to a destroyed object, here. When an object is returned from a function, it is a temporary object that gets destroyed as soon as it is used. You can save the returned value in a discrete object, for example:

```
Password pass2 = Generator->GenerateNewPass("12345");
```

But saving the address of a temporary object results in a pointer to a destroyed temporary object, and attempting to dereference this pointer will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you are using `new` everywhere, where you don't have to. This is not Java! You then went and leaked every single one of those dynamically-allocated objects. The generation functions get it right: just create *values*.

The second problem is that doing so has led you to believe that objects must be declared in pointer form wherever you use them. This is not true.

As a consequence of both of these things, you have "had to" take the address of temporary variables to even get a program in your style to compile. It's quite ironic, because only Visual Studio will even accept this code; the standard deems it illegal and using those pointers has undefined behaviour.

Finally, your `==` operation is logically incorrect as you are comparing pointers, rather than the things being pointed to.

Instead, simply:

```
int main()
{
    Password pass1("12345");

    PassGenerator Generator;
    Password pass2 = Generator.GenerateNewPass("12345");

    Password saltedPass = Generator.GenerateSaltedPass("1234", 4);

    cout << "Passwords are same?  " << (pass1 == pass2) << endl;
    cout << pass1 << endl; 
    cout << pass2 << endl;
    cout << saltedPass << endl;
}
```

Comment: Honestly I hate using pointers everywhere.... but for some strange reason at uni they force us... we got this policy that we need ot be able to perfectly and correctly handle the memory....

Comment: @Veneno odd because they are actually making that impossible. The proper way to do that in C++ is RAII

Comment: @Veneno: Then I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that they have forced you to imperfectly and incorrectly handle the memory. You cannot do what they ask without making a very poor and error-prone class design.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Every exam has this bolded at the bottom of it... its like the rules Idk...

Notes: Programming language C ++. Fully handle memory. Respect encapsulation rules.
Declarations in class, out of class definition. Use initialization lists of constructors. Avoid unnecessary copying
facilities. Ensure work with constant objects wherever possible.

Comment: @Veneno: None of that suggests to me that you need to use pointers and `new` everywhere.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hmmm... well the handle memory thing means we have to assign memory on a heap and not a stack... as far as I know that is dynamicly allocating so I need new and pointers.... Idk...

Comment: @Veneno: That sounds like a reach to me, given the wording shown above. However, schools imposing such requirements is certainly not unheard of.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. in these small programs its not reallly a problem but they are probably trying to make that into a habbit when we work on bigger projects and apps, performance wise I guess... but still there are better ways right?

Comment: @Veneno: Yeah, see, the problem is that the habit they are teaching you is a very bad habit. It doesn't really have anything to do with "performance wise I guess". If anything, needless dynamic allocation is _bad_ for performance...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is quite simple. You are taking the address of temporary `Password`s, which are destroyed on the return of each of the `generate` functions. To fix, *stop using pointers*, or change the `generate` functions so that they return a pointer.